# RHN won't update currently entitled RHEL v5 server

Tags: rhel5, rhn

I recently purchased RHEL v6 so I was able to get entitlements on my recently upgraded RHEL v4 machine to v5 (v6 is down the road currently).

However, in the web interface I run the updates, it fails as it just shows pending with the stopwatch icon.  If I run rhn_check the stop watch icon disappears and goes back to not installed.  If I login using rhn_register it says the system is already setup for updates but it won't update.  After doing an update from the website, I ran rhn_check -vv and got this as my results:

```
[root@intranet ~]# rhn_check -vv
D: check_action {'action': "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n<methodCall>\n<methodName>errata.update</methodName>\n<params>\n<param>\n<value><array><data>\n<value><int>11632</int></value>\n</data></array></value>\n</param>\n</params>\n</methodCall>\n", 'version': 2, 'id': 203338917}
updating login info
logging into up2date server
successfully retrieved authentication token from up2date server
D: logininfo: {'X-RHN-Server-Id': xxx, 'X-RHN-Auth-Server-Time': '1308081188.41', 'X-RHN-Auth': 'xxx', 'X-RHN-Auth-Channels': [['rhel-i386-server-5', '20110613025406', '1', '1']], 'X-RHN-Auth-User-Id': '', 'X-RHN-Auth-Expire-Offset': '3600.0'}
D: handle_action {'action': "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n<methodCall>\n<methodName>errata.update</methodName>\n<params>\n<param>\n<value><array><data>\n<value><int>11632</int></value>\n</data></array></value>\n</param>\n</params>\n</methodCall>\n", 'version': 2, 'id': 203338917}
D: handle_action actionid = 203338917, version = 2
D: do_call errata.update ([11632],)
D: Called update [['perl', 0, 0, '']]
Loading "rhnplugin" plugin
Loading "installonlyn" plugin
D: Downloading Packages:
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 37017186
D: Sending back response ((6,), 'Error while executing packages action: Refusing to automatically import keys when running unattended.\nUse "-y" to override.', {})
D: do_call packages.checkNeedUpdate ('rhnsd=1',)
D: local action status:  (0, 'rpm database not modified since last update (or package list recently updated)', {})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search yielded numerous results. [Google search for redhat Use "-y" to override](http://www.google.com/search?q=redhat%20Use%20%22-y%22%20to%20override%20Google%20search%20for%20redhat%20Use%20%22-y%22%20to%20override)

The first response was: [yum-rhn-plugin bug fix update](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2008-0360.html). Take a look at it. It may help you.

Comment: I did that Google search as well, though it seemed that a handful of updates went through not all, but I think it does resolve the -y problem I been having.  I think my questions had been answered.

Comment: well i was wrong, every update failed again...  Error while executing packages action: Error Downloading Packages: subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386: failed to retrieve getPackage/subversion-1.6.11-7.el5_6.4.i386.rpm from rhel-i386-server-5 error was [Errno 4] IOError: neon-0.25.5-10.el5_4.1.i386: failed to retrieve getPackage/neon-0.25.5-10.el5_4.1.i386.rpm from rhel-i386-server-5 error was [Errno 4] IOError: [[6]]

Comment: it seems it isn't my network as i tried with two different T1s (different ISPs) and both are failing.  i will try to contact redhat again but what makes no sense is, i had two individual updates that did succeed but not sure why these are failing.

Answer (score 0):

> D: Sending back response ((6,), 'Error
>   while executing packages action:
>   Refusing to automatically import keys
>   when running unattended.\nUse "-y" to
>   override.', {})

this kinda points to the issue. But in any case, if you have RHN then you should have support. Why ask on a forum when you can ask Red Hat?

Comment: how do I add the -y to override?  I am using the web interface.  I asked here because I don't have full support, just updates.  I already opened up a ticket with redhat but customer service said I need to have paid support which my company lacks.